# Flutter column widget - expand all buttons according to the widest button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a column widget with two buttons.

I want all the buttons to have the same width without specifying a hard coded width.

I need all the buttons to expand to the width of the widest button.

Thanks!

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
          child: Align(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Login'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
          child: Align(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Create new account'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this(Expensive widget)

```dart
class MyCustomForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: IntrinsicWidth(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Login'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Create new account'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: duplicate question bro :)

Comment: It is easier to answer rather than finding duplicate for me , btw asking question should suggest this duplicate one

Comment: yeah it is :P. But, we should close duplicate ones to avoid cluttering of dup questions on SO ;)